# Div is taking up space through CSS that it shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to set up a post that will appear on my site with early stages of css to lay out everything. I have color coded everything to make it easier to see whats going on. You can see it in this: https://jsfiddle.net/k3wpz49b/

My problem is that I have the last div called `details_wrapper` that is supposed to go where the red section is but it keeps going to the left all the way. When I inspect in on chrome it says that it is taking up the entire space. I can not figure out why this is happening.

My code is here :

```
<div class="post_wrapper">
<div class="profile_image">


</div>
<div class="body_wrapper">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
    <div class="description">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="details_wrapper">

</div>
```

```
    .post_wrapper{
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
.profile_image{
    width: 175px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
}
.body_wrapper{
    width: 475px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
}
.title{
    height: 40px;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.description{
    height: 80px;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
.details_wrapper{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry I meant details_wrapper

Comment: So like this https://jsfiddle.net/k3wpz49b/1/?

Comment: add `float:right;` to details_wrapper's css

Comment: I could have swore I tried that. You are right it does work

Comment: suppose you meant `details_wrapper` that sits on the left behind all of this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to add `float: left` to the `details_wrapper`

https://jsfiddle.net/k3wpz49b/5/